# Given some $x ∈ ℝ$, find some $y ∈ ℝ: x < y < \left \lfloor {x+1} \right \rfloor $

Tags: trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Motivation:

[This](http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Floor/27/02/) Wolfram webpage suggests that you can represent a floor function analytically as:

$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor := x + \frac{\tan^{-1}(\ \cot(\pi x) \ )}{\pi} - \frac{1}{2} \ \\ \forall x ∈ ℝ \backslash ℤ $$

which is valid whenever x is **not** an integer.

Yes, it works (and I'm amazed).

---

However, I'd like to safely use the function even when x is an integer, hence the question. It's not hard per-se, my brain just doesn't like me right now.

---

*I appreciate any guidance you have to offer.*

Comment: The floor of an integer is itself, simple as that.

Comment: If $x$ is an integer then $\lceil x \rceil=x$.

Comment: Somewhat heuristically, you cannot compose "nice" functions to make a floor function that works everywhere, because "nice" functions are continuous on their domains, and the floor function is not. (Note that the version of the floor function described above is continuous, because the points where it would be discontinuous are not part of the domain.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries I tried using a dirac-delta to fill in the removable discontinuities (see answer). I'm a simple boy: I see dirac, I use dirac.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel the problem is that the function in the question stem becomes undefined at integer values of x. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm solving a problem wherein I must extract the contents of the floor function, which hopefully explains why I'm bothering to express the floor function using more tenable functions, like the trigs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to the problem stated in the question title, rather than in the paragraph below, is 
$$
y = \frac{x + \lfloor x+1 \rfloor}{2}.
$$

Mees de Vries's comment explains nicely why you're not likely to find a "pretty" answer in terms of known continuous functions.

Comment: there's one minor problem with this approach: the definition of the floor in the question breaks down for integer x. Thus, x+1 is an integer, and the problem persists.

Comment: The floor of an integer, is the integer of it self. So if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\lfloor x+1 \rfloor := x+1$.  Hence, if $x$ is an integer, the interval is $[x,x+1]$, and the average is clearly in it.

Comment: I *know* the definition of "floor"; it's what Raymond describes. The mess in the question happens to equal the floor when $x \notin \Bbb Z$, but so what? My answer provides a way to compute the thing asked for in the question; it uses the well-known "floor" function. That's *not* what you asked for in the body of the question, but as I said, there's unlikely to be any solution to the problem as written in the body.

Answer (score 0):

The function:$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor := x + \frac{\tan^{-1}(\ \cot(\pi x) \ )}{\pi} - \frac{1}{2} \ \\ \forall x ∈ ℝ \backslash ℤ $$

breaks down for x ∈ ℤ because $\cot(\pi x) $ does not exist.

A potential fix is to add a function $\phi(x)$ that only turns on when x is an integer.

Thus:

$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor := \phi(x) + x + \frac{\tan^{-1}(\ \cot(\pi (\phi(x)+x)) \ )}{\pi} - \frac{1}{2} $$

where

$$ \phi(x):=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^{\cos(2\pi x)-1}{\delta(\tau)\ d\tau} \ + \ \frac{1}{4}\int_{1-\cos(2\pi x)}^{1}{\delta(\tau)\ d\tau}\ $$

and $x∈ℝ$, which gets the job done.

You could probably write $\phi(x)$ using unit step functions.

---

The dirac-delta functional is technically a distribution, so maybe I cheated a little.

*Best.*